# Rails js action won't run code after partial render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, renderpartial, jquery-effects

I'm trying to add a newly created partial to an existing list of partials that gets rendered in my `create.js.erb` controller action response, and it would be really nice to scroll to the item and indicate the new addition by highlighting it or something.  I have gotten the hang of the scrolling part in my client side javascript, but all the effects that come after the partial render in `create.js.erb` just don't get run.  There are plenty of examples of this being possible, I'm just not sure why mine doesn't work.

### First try: `create.js.erb`

```
$('#allTab').removeClass('active');
$('#activeTab').addClass('active');
$('#completeTab').removeClass('active');
// TODO: Make sure that li below gets an id="campaign_####" before this render happens.
$('#activeTabList').append("<li><%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'fundraisers/fundraiser', locals: {f: @fundraiser, g: @group}) %></li>")
var number_li = $('#activeTabList li').length;
var $newcampaigndiv = $('#activeTabList li').last().children("panel");
$('#number_of_campaigns').text('Campaigns (' + number_li + ')');
$("body").animate({
    scrollTop: $newcampaigndiv.offset().top
}, {
    duration: 600,
    queue: false
});
$('#activeTabList li').last().children("panel").effect('highlight');
```

### Second try: `create.js.erb`

```
$('#allTab').removeClass('active');
$('#activeTab').addClass('active');
$('#completeTab').removeClass('active');
// TODO: Make sure that li below gets an id="campaign_####" before this render happens.
$.when($('#activeTabList').append("<li><%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'fundraisers/fundraiser', locals: {f: @fundraiser, g: @group}) %></li>")).done(function () {
    var number_li = $('#activeTabList li').length;
    var $newcampaigndiv = $('#activeTabList li').last().children("panel");
    alert('gets here at least');
    $('#number_of_campaigns').text('Campaigns (' + number_li + ')');
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: $newcampaigndiv.offset().top + $newcampaigndiv.height() / 4 - $(window).height() / 2
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        queue: false
    });
    $('#activeTabList li').last().children("panel").effect('highlight');
});
```

I was hesitant to ask this question because I'm not opposed to accepting the fact that I'm just not traversing the dom correctly, but I've been trying all sorts of combinations to get it right.

### Also:

If I try to embed more ruby to set the id of the `<li>` surrounding the partial, it breaks the whole action and the partial is not rendered.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: I can't see any ruby code in the function which is triggered in the done, so you might be able to move that code into a method in one of your javascript files. It would make the 'create.js.erb' cleaner and easier to debug, plus then the server would not send that piece of code to the browser many times.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  To clarify, you are suggesting taking the second try's code and calling a function in the .done() rather than defining it there?  I'll give it a shot later after work.  Other than that it seems like it should work to you?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I recommend using a tool like Firebug with Firefox (Chrome has something like that build in) with this kind of issues, if you are not already doing so. With that you can monitor easily what the server is sending to your browser and see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Alright, I'll give Firebug a shot.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to access the javascript files that correspond to my controller actions in Chrome's  Dev Tools window.  Does Firebug allow me to step through my create.js.erb, update.js.erb, etc.?  I use Rubymine, and I can put a breakpoint only on the line that does the actual partial render, but Rubymine doesn't let me add javascript to my list of watches, so I can't really utilize this.  It would be nice to be able to identify if I'm having traversal issues.

Comment: Firebug can not see your create.js.erb etc. because those files are on the server. Server renders those files and sends the end result to the browser. In Firebugs "Net" tab you can see what the browser gets from the server.

Comment: Alright, I'll check that out after work today.  On top of trying to scroll to the item and highlighting it, I'm also trying to make sure that a form in that new item will have a datepicker input item as well.  Haven't been able to hook that up, but I'm assuming I'll be able to get some information from the "Net" tab like you are saying.